# Why is MySQL import slower than export?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I just exported a 150 MB table using **mysqldump** from command line. It took about 5 seconds to export it.

However when I try to import the same file it takes up to 5 minutes.

Why is import slower than export and is there a way to speed it up? I need to export/import tables that are greater than 1 GB.

Does it have to do something with locks? Since select is reading data therefore exporting it would be faster and import is writing data and could be slower since it needs write locks.

Comment: It could be indexes on your tables.

Comment: is the destination physical drive the same as the database drive? The indices are indeed also a big problem at write time.

Comment: im exporting from a server hosted on one of the hosting companies and importing on localhost machine

Comment: Usually throwing up is quicker than eating it in the first place - Something to do with masticating - sorry about the metaphor.

Comment: oh, your machine might just be slower than your server's harddrive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing is slower than reading, on almost any medium. In a DBMS, indexes have to be maintained, constraints have to be checked, space has to be allocated, transaction boundaries have to be oberved, transaction loggging has to happen so that rollbacks will work, ...

Answer (score 1):

Reading is a lot simpler than writing in the DBMS.  And that's before you consider transaction logging.
For instance, you have to write the row of data; you also have to update all the indexes on the table where the new row is.  That means there's a lot more than a single I/O per written record.

Comment: any way writing can be improved?

Comment: If you're importing large quantities of data, don't build the indexes until the data loading is complete.  That way, you build the indexes all at once, rather than perpetually updating.  That often saves a lot of work.  The downside is that the non-existent indexes can't reject rows if you're relying on the indexes to enforce uniqueness constraints, etc.